# Odoo sale.layout_category module

Tags: odoo

I created a test accounting odoo application in http://odoo.com,
The odoo version is Odoo 11.0+e (Enterprise Edition).

When creating an invoice line, I should fill the field layout_category_id which is attached to the module  sale.layout_category, but I can not find this module.

[image]

Can someone help me to activate this module?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding 'Sales' plugin to the app.
[image]